# Перенос данных из одной БД в другую удаленно

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть два сервера:
Сервер телефонии, на нем работает **CDR** модуль который каким-то волшебным образом записывает ВСЮ инфу о вызовах (in/out) в локальную базу *asteriskcdr* на сервере mysql.

Сервер БД, на нем локальная база *calllsit* с ОСНОВНОЙ инфой о вызовах и имеющая иную структуру.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, как лучше переносить информацию из уже готовой базы в новую, по TCP/IP без лишних сложностей?

P.S.
Я придумал сделать десктопный клиент (на C# например) для переноса, который будет селектом или иным образом брать инфу из нужных столбцов и дальше INPUT'ом вставлять в новую базу. Этот подход верный?

Comment: Судя по гуглу в MySQL есть тип таблиц FEDERATED. например https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html  Правда судя по всему надо пересобирать MySQL с поддержкой этого. С помощью них можно таблицу с одного сервера видеть на другом сервере. после чего весь перенос данных можно делать одной хранимой процедурой на самом mysql. И даже если без этого то я бы все таки делал скрипт на одном из серверов и запускал например по крону или что бы постоянно активен был. третья машина (desktop) добавляет нестабильность в схему

Comment: Приложение будет скорее всего на сервере БД. В любом случае клиент нужен именно десктопный, а не web, просто думал подключать его у двум базам, хотя если он будет работать но-стоп это уже не клиент, а тоже какой-то модуль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбор решения зависит от технических требований. Раз вы говорите, что структура разная, то бэкап/рестор или репликация это не ваш случай.

Если обновление нужно производить в режиме, близком к реальному времени, пусть этим занимается то же приложение, которое пишет в исходную таблицу. Используйте какой-нибудь колбэк на событие обновления. Тогда данные в базах будут более-менее согласованы в произвольный момент времени.

Если это некая статистика, обновление можно делать периодически: в конце дня или один раз в отчетный период, тогда пусть по расписанию в малонагруженное время запускается скрипт переноса.

Comment: Суть ясна, не делать, то ,что я придумал) спасибо)